# How to convert get Days,Weeks,Months,Years from Days(in terms of daily savings)

Tags: java, android, math

So I am working on a little savings app for Android. 
I have three values thats I need to work with.
I have a value for the daily amount of savings, another for the monthly savings, and another for the yearly savings.
I then want to put in an object to purchase. And the output the number of years,months,days,weeks till you can buy this object.

I want it to be formated as 
You will be able to afford this item in 1 Month 2 Weeks 3 Days

```
double days_till;
 int years;
 int months;
 int weeks;


 days_till = price/ daily_savings;


 years = (int) (days_till/365);

 int new_days_till = (int) ((days_till - years) * 365);

 months = new_days_till/30;

 int new_days_till2 = new_days_till - months*30;

 weeks = new_days_till2/7;

 int new_days_till3 = new_days_till2 - 7 * weeks;


 String days_till_string = String.valueOf(years) + " years" + String.valueOf(months) + " months" + String.valueOf(weeks) + " weeks" + String.valueOf(new_days_till3) + "days";
```

Comment: You just have to figure out the math and do it.  Weeks = Days/7.  Months = Days/30.  Years = Days/365.  Write some code and try it!

Comment: btw, to get days, math is `price/daily_savings` rounded up.

Comment: I'm trying to think of some good ways to do this. I guess I am having a bad coding day...

Comment: Would using modulus be a good approach?

Comment: I just updated with code...Any further help?

Answer (score 2):

This method might be of interest to you: [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#getRelativeTimeSpanString(long, long, long, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#getRelativeTimeSpanString%28long,%20long,%20long,%20int%29)

Answer (score 0):

I cant tell you how to do this in code, but how I would try to solv the problem.
1. I would find how many days I would need to save, then I would find a date when I would be able to buy the product by ading that number of days to the start date.(startdate + n= enddate) This would give me a date, eg may 21th. Start endmounth - startmount would give med a number of mounts to save if the day og mounth was the same in both (endmounth - startmount = numbersofmounths). Further:
If I started to save on a day less than the day of endmounth, then I would need to subtract day of startmonth from day of endmounth to get number of days extra.(startday - endday=numbers of days extra) 
If I started to save on a day greater than the day of endmounth, I would need to subtract 1 from the numbers of mounts, and then find the extra days to show the user)maxdayofmounth - startday)+endday = number of days extra.
Then U just inform the user of numbers of mounts and days calculated.